# How to move focus at button in collectionview cell in tvos application?

Tags: ios, tvos, apple-tv, tvos9.1, tvos10

I am working on apple TV application. In my app, I have made a screen which has a collection view. In that case, I am able to move focus at collection view cell but not able to move focus to the button which is in collection view cell so can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

please give me an answer if anyone knows this answer.

Comment: what do you mean by focus ?

Comment: Focus means in tv os application whenever focus move then you can able to click up to the button.

Comment: Better you can use interaction of the collection view cell.

Comment: @Karthick yes, I am able to interaction with collection view cell but in my application buttons are in collectionViewCell so how i click them?

Comment: What are the elements you have in your collection view cell?

Comment: @Karthick two buttons , two labels and one image view are in collection view cell.

Comment: you need to at UIFocusGuide object in viewDidload that will allow user to move focus accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to solve this problem by adding below methods in collectionViewCell subclass.

## In CollectionViewCell Subclass

```
override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment]{
    // Condition
}
override func shouldUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool {
    // Condition
}
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    // Condition
}
```

you can see more at this link:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/VikasPrajapati27/CollectionViewFocus).

Comment: it's not working like expected, first it focused the first button, then second button and then lastly the cell... This is not correct UX.

Answer (score 1):

I think this page will guide to achieve what you want. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH5-SW4

It give good explaination of how focus engine will decide which object should get next focus. Below is great explanation step by step at [above link.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html)

Here is an example showing how focus might be determined:

1. The focus engine asks the root window for its preferredFocusedView,
   which returns its root view controller’s preferredFocusedView
   object.
2. The root view controller, a tab view controller, returns its
   select view controller’s preferredFocusedView object.
3. The select view controller overrides its preferredFocusedView method to    return a specific UIButton instance.
4. The UIButton instance returns self(the default), and is focusable, so it is chosen by the focus engine as the next focused view.

You have to override the preferredFoucsedView property of your UIView or UIViewController.

```
override weak var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    if someCondition {
        return theViewYouWant
    } else {
        return defaultView
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Slayter's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762840/how-can-i-force-focus-to-change-to-a-specific-view-in-tvos) answer